# PHPMailer doesn't send mail

Tags: phpmailer

Please help me. I am stuck into this for 1 month and didn't get any solution.
I use the following code.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'includes/PHPMailer.php';
require 'includes/SMTP.php';
require 'includes/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->HOST = "smtp.gmail.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = "true";

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

$mail->Port = "587";

$mail->Username = "Myemail";

$mail->Password = "My email password";

$mail->Subject = "Test Email";

$mail->setFrom("My email");
$mail->addReplyTo('My email');

$mail->Body = "This is plain text";

$mail->addAddress("My email");

if ($mail->Send() ) {
    echo "Sent";
}else{
    echo "ERROR";
}

$mail->smtpClose();

?>
```

Here I already off "Less secure app access" option. Here I want to send an email from the same email (Just for testing purpose). But the Code gets some error which I don't understand.......

`Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\includes\PHPMailer.php:1856 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\includes\PHPMailer.php(1598): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Wed, 15 A...', 'This is plain t...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\includes\PHPMailer.php(1434): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\index.php(36): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpmailer\includes\PHPMailer.php on line 1856`

Please help me guys.

Comment: do you tried another server? error says can't connect to server. Maybe you haven't well configured dns in server or your machine. Try nslookup smtp.gmail.com from command line.

Comment: Base your code on [the gmail example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), [read the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host) the error message points you at, and search before you post.

Comment: `        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);         `  here if I omit 'true' from the function it doesn't  show those errors. It goes to the else part of the code and gives 'ERROR' in the browser. The server is alright. I checked it.

Comment: I can not understand the fact please help me.